# What is wrong with my arduino code?

Tags: ethernet, arduino, java

I have created a project for basic ethernet shield and JAVA program communication. When I try to compile the code I get a error:

```
Default.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Default:33: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
Default:76: error: expected `}' at end of input
```

Please help.

My Code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
byte mac[] = { 
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1, 177);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 0, 0);
int redled = 2;
int yellowled = 3;
int greenled = 4;
char c = 0;
EthernetServer server(23);
boolean alreadyConnected = false;

void setup() {

    pinMode( redled, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( yellowled, OUTPUT );
    pinMode( greenled, OUTPUT );
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ;

  Serial.println("Server Is Ready!");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  Serial.println("Ready For Connections!");
  }


void loop() {
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    if (!alreadyConnected) {
      client.flush();    
      Serial.println("Client Connected To Server.");
      alreadyConnected = true;
    } 
  if( client.available() > 0 )
    {
      c = client.read();
        switch( c )
        {
            case '1':
                digitalWrite( redled, HIGH );
                break;
            case '2':
                digitalWrite( redled, LOW );
                break;
            case '3':
                digitalWrite( yellowled, HIGH );
                break;
            case '4':
                digitalWrite( yellowled, LOW );
                break;
            case '5':
                digitalWrite( greenled, HIGH );
                break;
            case '6':
                digitalWrite( greenled, LOW );
                break;
            case '8':
                digitalWrite( redled, LOW );
                digitalWrite( yellowled, LOW );
                digitalWrite( greenled, LOW );
                break;
            case '7':
                digitalWrite( redled, HIGH );
                digitalWrite( yellowled, HIGH );
                digitalWrite( greenled, HIGH );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Chasing down unmatched curly braces has nothing to do with electronics design.  Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: This should go on StackOverflow although really you have made basic syntax error, a cup of coffee and you would find your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot an closing `}` after:

```
Serial.println("Ready For Connections!");
```

and after:

```
case '7':
                digitalWrite( redled, HIGH );
                digitalWrite( yellowled, HIGH );
                digitalWrite( greenled, HIGH );
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing end brackets for both setup and loop.